# Return sub combinations of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function which returns all the combinations in a list:

```
def sub_combinations(segment):
  if len(segment) == 1:
    yield (segment,)
  else:
    for x, j in enumerate(sub_combinations(segment[1:])):
      yield ((segment[0],),)+j
      for k in range(len(j)):
         yield (((segment[0],)+j[k]),) + (j[:k]) +(j[k+1:])
```

but how do I get it to return only the sub combinations:

```
((1,), (2,), (3,), (4,))
((1, 2), (3,), (4,))
((1, 3), (2,), (4,))
((1, 4), (2,), (3,))
((1,), (2, 3), (4,))
((1, 2, 3), (4,))
((1, 4), (2, 3))
((1,), (2, 4), (3,))
((1, 2, 4), (3,))
((1, 3), (2, 4))
((1,), (2,), (3, 4))
((1, 2), (3, 4))
((1, 3, 4), (2,))
((1,), (2, 3, 4))
```

instead of:

```
((1,), (2,), (3,), (4,))
((1, 2), (3,), (4,))
((1, 3), (2,), (4,))
((1, 4), (2,), (3,))
((1,), (2, 3), (4,))
((1, 2, 3), (4,))
((1, 4), (2, 3))
((1,), (2, 4), (3,))
((1, 2, 4), (3,))
((1, 3), (2, 4))
((1,), (2,), (3, 4))
((1, 2), (3, 4))
((1, 3, 4), (2,))
((1,), (2, 3, 4))
((1, 2, 3, 4),)  # remove this
```

when calling it with:

```
sub_combinations((1,2,3,4))
```

This is my attempt that doesn't work:

```
def sub_combinations(segment, d=0):
  if len(segment) == 1:
    yield (segment,)
  else:
    for x, j in enumerate(sub_combinations(segment[1:]), d+1):
      yield ((segment[0],),)+j
      for k in range(len(j)):
         r = (((segment[0],)+j[k]),) + (j[:k]) +(j[k+1:])
         if d == 0 and r == (segment,): continue
         yield r
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should split into 2 functions, each one have it's own functionality. The first just creates the combinations as you implemented, the second, just wraps it, and filters the un-desired segments.

Something like:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def get_combinations(segment):
    pass # your implementation


def get_sub_combinations(segment, filter_func=lambda x: x == segment):
    yield from filterfalse(filter_func, get_combinations(segment))
```